# Image size of MRI T2-weighted scans

Tags: resolution, medical

I have MRI T2-weighted scans of the human brain. However, the size of them is only 128x128 pixels each of 1.71875/1.71875 mm size. I use these scans to find the perfusion parameters: CBV, CBF and MTT. However, some people confused me saying that the quality of images is not enough for the analysis - even though the images are gathered from a medical institution.

I also heard some rumors that since the paramagnetic tracer is used during the scans the quality is sufficient, because we need to capture a flow of the tracer. If we increase the resolution, the time between scans will also increase and we won't capture a flow of the tracer correctly.

Are there any specialists in this area who could explain the situation of the images quality? Is it reasonably enough or it should be better?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: If you don't understand the idea behind this, it doesn't mean it is off-topic.

Comment: @Donatas: YuHao is probably right, you know. There is, after all, no code to be seen here.